# Encountered unknown tag 'with'

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates, jinja2

I am encountering the following error when attempting to use jinja2 templates with django 1.8 "Encountered unknown tag 'with'".

The same template works fine on my flask application but when attempting to use the with functionality of jinja 2 I get that error.

inside of the jinja template

```
{% with %}
    {% set vartest = 42 %}
    {{ vartest }}
{% endwith %}
```

inside of my jinja2 environment customization

```
def environment(**options):
    env = Environment(**options)
    env.globals.update({
        'static': staticfiles_storage.url,
        'url_for': reverse,
        'STATIC_URL': STATIC_URL
    })
    return env
```

Comment: Do you know which version of `jinja2` you are using? `with` was new in 2.3.

Comment: pip show gives me
Name: Jinja2
Version: 2.7.3

Comment: It seems that `with` is [an extension](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#with-extension), try adding `options.setdefault('extensions', []).append('jinja2.ext.with_')` before you create the `Environment`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue, please submit as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`with` statement](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#with-statement) was new in version 2.3 of Jinja; if you have something earlier, use `pip install --upgrade Jinja2` to get the latest version.

It's also [an extension](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#with-extension), so you'll have to include it in the `Environment`, e.g. by adding:

```
options.setdefault('extensions', []).append('jinja2.ext.with_')
```

Comment: Would you also add a note you can also put in it your settings file where it likely would go for most people i bet. I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: @Moylin I don't know the syntax for that; why not add it as a separate answer?

Comment: Just curious, was that functionality documented somewhere, i didn't even see where to pass extension configuration anywhere.

Comment: Be nice if the Jinja docs referenced this where the with statement is documented...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be configured in your settings file.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            'your/django/templates',
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2',
        'DIRS': [
            'your/jinja2/templates.',
        ],
        'OPTIONS':{
            'environment': 'app.project.jinja2.environment',
            'extensions': ['jinja2.ext.with_']}
    }
]
```